# document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8").disabled = 'false';

Tags: javascript

I want to enable the disabled text field based on selection of checkbox, so below  is the JavaScript code to enable the text field based on selection of check box, which is not working for me and am using the struts 1.3 HTML tags

```js
if(document.getElementsByName("cad.question7").checked = 'true'){
    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8").disabled = 'false';
}
```

```xml
<html:checkbox  value="Y" property="cad.question7" onclick="javascript:enableText7();" />
<bean:message key="cm.assessments.cad.question.7.a" />
<html:text size="10" disabled="true" property="cad.question7.answer8" tabindex="68" />
```

Comment: `=`? Did you mean `==` or `===`?

Comment: `'true'`?`'false'`? Did you mean `true`, `false`?

Answer (score 5):

[**getElementsByName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns a [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection).

To access each element inside the collection either iterate through them or if you only have one, access the first one, similar to this:

```
document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8")[0].disabled = false;
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/suHcc/) - Access first item in `HTMLCollection`

---

If you expect multiple matches iterate through them similar to this:

```
var index;
var elements = document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8");
var count = elements.length;

for(index = 0; index < count; index++){
    elements[index].disabled = false;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3HJUn/) - Iterate through all items in the `HTMLCollection`

---

In addition when executing a conditional evaluation you use `==` or `===` as a single `=` will assign the right value to the left and not compare them with each other.

Your complete code may look similar to this, assuming only a single match is expected:

```
if(document.getElementsByName("cad.question7")[0].checked){
    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8")[0].disabled = false;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JTfya/) - Example of new code above

---

Answer (score 1):

It should be boolean. `disabled` takes boolean value and also `getElementsByName` return multiple elements in an array.

Issue with your `disabled="false"` is that it still leaves the attrbute `disabled` in your text input element.

Try this:-

```
if(document.getElementsByName("cad.question7")[0].checked){

    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8")[0].disabled = false;
}
```

#### References:-

#### [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection)

#### [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled)

Comment: If you say that `getElementsByName` returns a list why don't you respect that?

Answer (score 1):

- In the if-condition, you want to use the `==` or `===` comparison operator, not the `=` assignment operator. But comparing against booleans is senseless, just use the boolean itself (or its negation).
- `document.getElementsByName` returns not a single element, but a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList). You will need to iterate over it, or - for simplicity - access its first item.
- Both the `checked` and `disabled` properties are boolean. You should not compare/assign string to them, but booleans.

```
if (document.getElementsByName("cad.question7")[0].checked) {
    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8")[0].disabled = false;
}
```

You might even go with this:

```
var question = document.getElementsByName("cad.question7")[0],
    answer = document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8")[0];
answer.disabled = !question.checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below JavaScript codes you can use, your wish.,

But i would suggest you to use this (First one):

```
if(document.getElementsByName("cad.question7").checked){
    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8")[0].disabled = false;
}
```

**or**

```
if(document.getElementsByName("cad.question7").checked == true){
    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8").disabled = false;
}
```

**or**

```
var chkTest = document.getElementsByName("cad.question7");
if(chkTest.checked){
    document.getElementsByName("cad.question7.answer8").disabled = false;
}
```